# Terras Conjecture in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, integer-division

I'm having a problem generating the Terras number sequence.

[image: Terras formula]

Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Terras
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int Terras(int n)
        {
            if (n <= 1)
            {
                int return_value = 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Terras generated : " + return_value);

                return return_value;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((n % 2) == 0)
                {
                    // Even number
                    int return_value = 1 / 2 * Terras(n - 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("Terras generated : " + return_value);

                    return return_value;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Odd number
                    int return_value = 1 / 2 * (3 * Terras(n - 1) + 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("Terras generated : " + return_value);

                    return return_value;
                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TERRAS1");
            Terras(1); // should generate 1

            Console.WriteLine("TERRAS2");
            Terras(2); // should generate 2 1 ... instead of 1 and 0

            Console.WriteLine("TERRAS5");
            Terras(5); // should generate 5,8,4,2,1 not 1 0 0 0 0

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I know the basics of recursion, but I don’t understand why this doesn’t work.

I observe that the first number of the sequence is actually the number that you pass in, and subsequent numbers are zero.

Comment: The examples given don't appear to satisfy the formula. For example, if `t0 == 2`, then `t1 == 1/2 * (3*2+1) == 3.5` (since 1 is odd). Either the formula or the examples are wrong - figure out which.

Comment: Yes, but no matter the type of data type that i evaluate it `int` or `double` it gives me the same wrong answer, what should i do?

Comment: How do you know the answer is wrong? What answer is correct? Again, the examples you've shown don't satisfy the formula you've given. They are wrong answers for this problem. They might be correct answers for some other problem that you haven't shown.

Comment: This appears to also have the name [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `1 / 2 * Terros(n - 1);` to `Terros(n - 1)/2;`

Also `1 / 2 * (3 * Terros(n - 1) + 1);` to `(3 * Terros(n - 1) + 1)/2;`

`1/2 * ...` is simply `0 * ...` with `int` math.

---

[Edit]

Recursion is wrong  **and** formula is mis-guided.  Simple iterate

```
public static void Terros(int n) {
  Console.Write("Terros generated :");
  int t = n;
  Console.Write(" " + t);
  while (t > 1) {
    int t_previous = t;
    if (t_previous%2 == 0) {
      t = t_previous/2;
    }
    else {
      t = (3*t_previous+1)/2;
    }
    Console.Write(", " + t);
  }
  Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

The "n is even"  should be "t(subscript n-1) is even" - same for "n is odd".

Comment: Works sweet, thank you. I understand the concept, basically you make a job like recursivity, keepeng the previous `t` and just compute those two formulas, correct? And one more thing, is there a recursive formula for this? basically you will have to "carry" `t` with you like this `TerrosRecursive(int n,int t)` or `TerrosRecursive(int n,int current_number,int t)`, what do you think?

Comment: @Master345 I think `void TerrosRecursive()` only needs 1 parameter `t` for t(sub 1) or later.  It depends on what you want the function to do.  If it is to print and return a `void` - we are done.  Should you want the i'th parameter in the sequence returned, of course you need `i` and `t`.   Good luck!

Comment: @Palec The editing done to the question changing "Terros" to "Terras" hides an original issue to the problem: By using "Terros", it became more difficult to assist the OP; see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647824/more-info-on-conjuncture-of-terros as web searches led nowhere.  Rather a strike-though "Terros" with a following "Terras" would have provided a correction, yet maintained the problem's evolution.

Comment: @chux I felt that this mistake was mainly of historical interest and had nothing to do with the actual problem. The problem was mainly with code which I think is the important thing to preserve. Googling for Terras is still hard. I intended to add an answer with that mistake described, it just took long to write as I did other things in parallel. Now it’s here. This obsoletes my comments, deleting them.

Answer (score 2):

```
  int return_value = 1 / 2 * Terros(n - 1);
  int return_value = 1 / 2 * (3 * Terros(n - 1) + 1);
```

Unfortunately you've hit a common mistake people make with ints.

(int)1 / (int)2 will always be 0.

Comment: i know the difference between `(int)1/2` and `(double)1/2` but if i make the whole function `double` it gives me `1 , 0.5 , 1.25 , 0.625 , 1.4375`

Comment: @Master345: For what input value? Your first `if` should restrict that.

Comment: `Terros(5)` when i have double ... i have a feeling that i have to take it from the last number to the first, invert processing or something

Answer (score 0):

Since `1/2` is an *integer divison* it's always *0*; in order to correct the math, just
*swap the terms*: not `1/2*n` but `n/`2; instead of `1/2* (3 * n + 1)` put `(3 * n + 1) / 2`.

Another issue: do not put computation (Terros) and output (Console.WriteLine) *in the 
same function*

```
public static String TerrosSequence(int n) {
  StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

  // Again: dynamic programming is far better here than recursion
  while (n > 1) {
    if (Sb.Length > 0)
      Sb.Append(",");

    Sb.Append(n);

    n = (n % 2 == 0) ? n / 2 : (3 * n + 1) / 2;
  }

  if (Sb.Length > 0)
    Sb.Append(",");

  Sb.Append(n);

  return Sb.ToString();
}


// Output: "Terros generated : 5,8,4,2,1"
Console.WriteLine("Terros generated : " + TerrosSequence(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

*The existing answers guide you in the correct direction, but there is no ultimate one. I thought that summing up and adding detail would help you and future visitors.*

## The problem name

The original name of this question was “Conjuncture of Terros”. First, it is [conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjecture), second, the modification to the original Collatz sequence you used comes from [Riho Terras](http://www.geni.com/people/Riho-Terras/6000000009517751918)* (not Terros!) who proved the [Terras Theorem](http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/terras.html) saying that for almost all *t₀* holds that *∃n ∈ ℕ: tₙ < t₀*. You can read more about it on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CollatzProblem.html) and [chux’s question on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/647824/105373).

** While searching for who is that R. Terras mentioned on MathWorld, I found not only the [record on Geni.com](http://www.geni.com/people/Riho-Terras/6000000009517751918), but also probable author of that record, his niece Astrid Terras, and [her family’s genealogy](http://astridterras.com/genealogy/terras.html). Just for the really curious ones. ☺*

## The formula

You got the formula wrong in your question. As the table of sequences for different *t₀* shows, you should be testing for [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_%28mathematics%29) of *tₙ₋₁* instead of *n*.

[image: t_n={1/2t_(n-1) for t_(n-1) even; 1/2(3t_(n-1)+1) for t_(n-1) odd]

*Formula taken from [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CollatzProblem.html).*

Also the second table column heading is wrong, it should read *t₀, t₁, t₂, …* as *t₀* is listed too.

You repeat the mistake with testing *n* instead of *tₙ₋₁* in your code, too. If output of your program is precisely specified (e.g. when checked by an automatic judge), think once more whether you should output *t₀* or not.

## Integer vs float arithmetic

When making an operation with two integers, you get an integer. If a float is involved, the result is float. In both branches of your condition, you compute an expression of this form:

```
1 / 2 * …
```

1 and 2 are integers, therefore the division is integer division. Integer division always rounds down, so the expression is in fact

```
0 * …
```

which is (almost*) always zero. Mystery solved. But how to fix it?

Instead of multiplying by one half, you can divide by two. In even branch, division by 2 gives no remainder. In odd branch, *tₙ₋₁* is odd, so *3 · tₙ₋₁* is odd too. Odd plus 1 is even, so division by two always produces remainder equal to zero in both branches. Integer division is enough, the result is precise.

Also, you could use float division, just replace `1` with `1.0`. But this will probably not give correct results. You see, all members of the sequence are integers and you’re getting float results! So rounding with `Math.Round()` and casting to integer? Nah… If you can, always evade using floats. There are very few use cases for them, I think, most having something to do with graphics or numerical algorithms. Most of the time you don’t really need them and they just introduce [round-off errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error).

** Zero times whatever could produce [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) too, but let’s ignore the possibility of “whatever” being from special float values. I’m just pedantic.*

## Recursive solution

Apart from the problems mentioned above, your whole recursive approach is flawed. Obviously you intended `Terras(n)` to be *tₙ*. That’s not utterly bad. But then you forgot that you supply *t₀* and search for *n* instead of the other way round.

To fix your approach, you would need to set up a “global” variable `int t0` that would be set to given *t₀* and returned from `Terras(0)`. Then `Terras(n)` would really return *tₙ*. But you wouldn’t still know the value of *n* when the sequence stops. You could only repeat for bigger and bigger *n*, ruining time complexity.

Wait. What about caching the results of intermediate `Terras()` calls in an `ArrayList<int> t`? `t[i]` will contain result for `Terras(i)` or zero if not initialized. At the top of `Terras()` you would add `if (n < t.Count() && t[n] != 0) return t[n];` for returning the value immediately if cached and not repeating the computation. Otherwise the computation is really made and just before returning, the result is cached:

```
if (n < t.Count()) {
    t[n] = return_value;
} else {
    for (int i = t.Count(); i < n; i++) {
        t.Add(0);
    }
    t.Add(return_value);
}
```

Still not good enough. Time complexity saved, but having the `ArrayList` increases space complexity. Try tracing (preferably manually, pencil & paper) the computation for `t0 = 3; t.Add(t0);`. You don’t know the final *n* beforehand, so you must go from 1 up, till `Terras(n)` returns 1.

Noticed anything? First, each time you increment `n` and make a new `Terras()` call, you add the computed value at the end of cache (`t`). Second, you’re always looking just one item back. You’re computing the whole sequence from the bottom up and you don’t need that big stupid `ArrayList` but always just its last item!

## Iterative solution

OK, let’s forget that complicated recursive solution trying to follow the top-down definition and move to the bottom-up approach that popped up from gradual improvement of the original solution. Recursion is not needed anymore, it just clutters the whole thing and slows it down.

End of sequence is still found by incrementing *n* and computing *tₙ*, halting when *tₙ = 1*. Variable `t` stores *tₙ*, `t_previous` stores previous *tₙ* (now *tₙ₋₁*). The rest should be obvious.

```
public static void Terras(int t) {
    Console.Write("Terras generated:");
    Console.Write(" " + t);
    while (t > 1) {
        int t_previous = t;
        if (t_previous % 2 == 0) {
            t = t_previous / 2;
        } else {
            t = (3 * t_previous + 1) / 2;
        }
        Console.Write(", " + t);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

*Variable names taken from chux’s answer, just for the sake of comparability.*

This can be deemed a primitive instance of [dynamic-programming](/questions/tagged/dynamic-programming) technique. The evolution of this solution is common to the whole class of such problems. Slow recursion, call result caching, dynamic “bottom-up” approach. When you are more experienced with dynamic programming, you’ll start seeing it directly even in more complicated problems, not even thinking about recursion.

Comment: Thank you so very much!! Very very good post!!
1. `Integer vs float arithmetic` -> yes, better devide by 2 than multiply by 1/2, got that
2. `round-off errors.` -> heared about them
3. `Try tracing (preferably manually, pencil & paper`  -> next time i should do that, like i'm the computer, to see what approach i will use, every time we must do this i think

Comment: 4. `Iterative solution` -> probably this is the method that is resulted from `pencil & paper` part, right?
5. `dynamic-programming` ? never heared about it, for me a recursive function is like this http://pastebin.com/cb8AWJ7M => just a function that calls itself and may have just 1 input parameter, i kinda get stuck when i try to have multiple
6. can you `help me with more problems like this`? i need a book/tutorials, please.

Comment: @Master345 You really cannot get how computers think if you don’t try to think like them. :-) Yes, iterative solution is what comes out of both pencil & paper solution (first that comes into your mind) and simulation of what I call recursion with cache. Recursion is a much more general concept then your simple one. Whole functional programming is built around it. E.g. `f(0, 0) :- !. f(1, 1) :- !. f(N, Fn) :- N1 is N - 1, f(N1, 0, 1, Fn). f(0, _, Fn, Fn) :- !. f(N, F0, F1, Fn) :- N1 is N - 1, F2 is F0 + F1, f(N1, F1, F2, Fn).` is Fibonacci sequence in Prolog. Break lines after dots.

Comment: @Master345 I chose Prolog as it is really easy to get even if you don’t know it. The left-hand side of `:-` is what comes in, the right-hand side is what happens then. You can safely ignore `!` for now. The last parameter is return value.

Comment: @Master345 Dynamic programming is algorithmization technique. If you do not get recursion well, I am afraid dynamic programming is too advanced for you. I think its tag wiki explains it well, tons of material on it lie all over the net… Memoization is what i call more familiarly caching.

Comment: @Master345 I see on your profile you are of my age. I guess you’re not computer science student. Programming just as a hobby? How much time do you want to invest in it? Maybe something systematic like Khan Academy or MIT lectures at YouTube will be a good fit for you, but it is going to be time-consuming. The best I can advise is to find someone for consultations and choosing study material that fits best your needs. Doing such a thing remotely is not flexible enough.